# Double data type causing error

Tags: c++, double

I am trying to get the fixed points for the tent equation. With the given initial conditions, the solution must be 0.6. Everything works fine when I use float for x0, but when I define x0 as a double, the solution changes to 0.59999 in 55th iteration, which causes further changes in the next iteration and so on. Why is there such a difference while choosing the data types?

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
main()

{
    double x0=.6;
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        if(x0<.5)
            x0=1.5*x0;
        else
            x0=1.5*(1-x0);

        cout << i << "\t" << x0 << endl;

    }

}
```

I have posted an image of the results. [Comparison of solutions - Float and Double](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTfsu.png)

Comment: You're being tricked by rounding. Adding `cout << setprecision(100)` will print all of the digits. And visit  the question [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: It is better to add your textual results as text if it is possible. The image you attached could be written in a code block of text in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real value of the 55-th iteration is `0.5999994832150543633275674437754787504673004150390625` when a `double` is used and `0.60000002384185791015625` for a `float` (on my system).

The difference between the two is in **how precise** the numbers are and the rounding is what throws you off.

BTW, neither of the two values is **absolutely accurate**, they are just **close enough approximations** and nothing more. With the `double` being "more precise".

---

**UPDATE**

After a few comments back and forth it turned out that there was no need for floating-point arithmetic to be gin with. Integers (slightly modified) do just fine **and** do not introduce any rounding.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to simulate dynamical systems where chaos comes into play. The equations are very sensitive to initial conditions. A slight change can cause huge changes in the future iterations. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Your question really depends on an **exact** definition of "this problem". Is the problem that the `float` behaves differently from `double`? Or is it that the precision of a `double` is not good enough for your needs? Or is the problem in the fact that binary numbers are not a good choice to represent decimal fractions?

Comment: My concern is that the solutions are deviating from its exact value (0.6 in this case) at a certain iteration causing the next iterations to return wrong solutions. Is there a way to obtain the exact value (0.6) at all iterations ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Do not use floating-point arithmetic. Multiply everything by `10` and use integers. Simple, fast, absolutely precise.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that since you are still multiplying by`1.5` (which is not an integer) that solution would work for the initial number `6` but not for, say, `5`.

Comment: I get "4,6" from the backend. Only for a particular user. How could this happen?